# Eclipse RCP: turn Eclipse product into rpm for openSUSe

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rpm, opensuse

I already created an Eclipse product for openSUSE using the delta pack (Eclipse 4.4). Currently I have installed my Eclipse 4.4 on Windows.

Now I try to create an rpm file that enables me to install my product on the openSUSE platform. Is there something like EclipseNSIS for Linux/OpenSUSE 64 Bit or some best practices? Unfortunately I have no experience in Linux/openSUSE at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what RCP or NSIS is, but you may be looking for:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:EclipsePlugins